# Does my simple calculator app correctly follow MVC Implementation?

Tags: javascript, html, css, model-view-controller

I created an extremely simple calculator app (a lot of improvements can be made in terms of reliability, input validation, etc) and I was trying to learn how to seperate the logic into Model, View, and Controller.

In my code, the Model hold all the data like the current number the user entered and the total. The View has a function that updates the number shown on the calculator. The Controller listens for I/O events (button clicks) and calls the respective Model and View methods to update data and the UI.

Here is a link to my CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/mvc-calculator-xzn7y8

Did I implement this correctly, in terms of seperating functionality between the Model, View, and Controller?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please have a look at the "How to ask" page: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask One of the requirements of StackOverflow is that you post your code here so that it's certain that the question (and your code) will be preserved for others to benefit from. Secondly, SO is primarily for helping people with programming problems. Your question might be a better fit for Code Review on Stack Exchange. Third, asking if this your code fits the MVC pattern calls for an opinion, which is off-topic on SO.

Comment: Any reason why you're not trying to learn a modern UI framework instead? Like React, Solid, Angular, Svelte, Vue, etc.